# When the viewpager is restarted, it keeps executing the previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The activity has a `homeFragment` that contains a `viewPager`.

If I refresh the `homeFragment`, the `viewPager` is also regenerated with the new data.

But The old fragment in the `viewPager` is re-executed before the adapter is created.

I do not get a clear answer even if I googleing it

**1. homeFragment refresh code :**

```
Fragment currentFragment = null;
currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.detach(currentFragment);
ft.attach(currentFragment);
ft.commit();
```

**2. adapter**

```
public class ChartViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

   public ChartViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int i) {
      ChartFragment chartFragment = new ChartFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("POSITION", i);
      chartFragment.setArguments(args);

      return chartFragment;
      //return ChartFragment.newInstance(i);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {

       switch (MainActivity.countryCode) {
          case "US":
            return 4;
          case "KR":
            return 3;
          case "DE":
            return 3;
          case "JP":
            return 1;
          case "CN":
            return 1;
          case "HK":
            return 1;
          case "FR":
            return 3;
          case "GB":
            return 2;
          default:
            return 3;
       }
   }
}
```

3. The closest approach is when executing `viewpager.setSaveParentEnlaled (false);` but If I see the log record, it will be called again same code several times, so I get error message.
4. It is not a problem If I change the **refresh method** to run the method in the `homeFragment` immediately without using **detach / attach way**, but the design should use the **detach / attach way**.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the

```
viewpager.setAdapter(null)
```

or in kotlin

```
viewpager.adapter = (null)
```

It will be reset the ViewPager to start position.

Comment: it doesn' work. problem is that regardless of the adapter, viewpager calls previous fragments. I think this problem is related to the detach/attach way